# Django: How to set sessionid cookie for AnonymousUser without using SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST

Tags: django, session, session-cookies, anonymous-users

I am attempting to track AnonymousUsers to figure out when they first come to the site, and when they then register to the website.

To do so, I created a middleware with the relevant functionality, but this initially assumed that each AnonymousUsers already had a session associated with it (i.e. sessionid cookie will be set in first response & associated session is already created in django_session). *Note: session app & middleware are present*

It seems that this is not the case, as looking at the session middleware, when an AnonymousUser first comes on the site, the session is never modified (Users do, since '_auth_user_id' and '_auth_user_backend' are set), and so is never created:

**SessionMiddleware.process_response**

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
    """
    If request.session was modified, or if the configuration is to save the
    session every time, save the changes and set a session cookie.
    """
    try:
        accessed = request.session.accessed
        modified = request.session.modified
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    else:
        if accessed:
            patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
        if modified or settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST:
            if request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close():
                max_age = None
                expires = None
            else:
                max_age = request.session.get_expiry_age()
                expires_time = time.time() + max_age
                expires = cookie_date(expires_time)
            # Save the session data and refresh the client cookie.
            request.session.save()
            response.set_cookie(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
                    request.session.session_key, max_age=max_age,
                    expires=expires, domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                    path=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH,
                    secure=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE or None,
                    httponly=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY or None)
    return response
```

---

**Attempt 1**

To try and overcome this, in my Middleware, which is placed below the Session Middleware, I would force a save() on the session to create it:

```
if hasattr(request, 'session') and not request.session.session_key:
    request.session.save()
```

This would provide the session_key, but unfortunately when SessionMiddleware.process_response is called, request.session.modified is still equal to False, and so the sessionid cookie is not set...

---

**Attempt 2**

One way to do this seems to modify the session, in an arbitrary way, to ensure that `request.session.modified == True`, in the SessionMiddleware.process_response:

```
if hasattr(request, 'session') and not request.session.session_key:
    request.session.save()
    request.session['some_variable'] = True
```

This seems to fix my problem, without resorting to `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`, which would be an overkill, but yet it does not seem quite right....

---

**Question**

How to make sure the session is created for an AnonymousUser with no previous visit, without explicitly modifying the session, or having `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST=True`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even explicitly modifying the session can fail (eg assigning an attribute to a session attribute).

You need to explicitly set `session.modified` to true

```
if hasattr(request, 'session') and not request.session.session_key:
    request.session.save()
    request.session.modified = True
```

Have a look at what the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) say on when sessions are saved.

Comment: Thanks Aidan, that works great. I am still not clear as to why the session module would not create a session, if one is not present, but  only when it is 'modified'...?

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. Glad you got it sorted anyway.